# nginx reverse proxy with docker containers and specific nested locations

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, redirect

I would like to set up nginx as a reverse proxy with multiple apps on docker containers permanently residing under specific locations, e.g.:

```
https://sub.example.com/wiki
https://sub.example.com/app1
https://sub.example.com/app2
```

In particular, I want to use the [mediawiki docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki/) next to other apps. This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: mediawiki
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - images:/var/www/html/images
      # - ./wiki/LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
    networks:
      - wiki
  
  database:
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_wiki
      MYSQL_USER: wikiuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wiki

  app1:
    # ...
    expose:
      - "4000"
    networks:
      - apps

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./certbot/data:/usr/share/nginx/html/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - mediawiki
    networks:
      - apps
      - wiki

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    # ...
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/logs:/var/log/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/data:/usr/share/nginx/html/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - apps
      - wiki

networks:
  apps:
  wiki:
```

The problem I am facing is that with the following `default.conf`, I am able to proxy the mediawiki container as well as the other apps, but certain links and resources return 404.

```
upstream testwiki {
    server mediawiki:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    
    server_name sub.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location /wiki/ {
        proxy_pass http://testwiki/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

I suspect the reason for this behavior is due to relational URLs, such as `<a href="/mw-config/index.php">complete the installation</a>`, directing requests to the root location instead of the nested one. I have tried a lot of things, such as `rewrite` (incl. regex), `sub_filter`, `proxy_redirect` and `proxy_set_header` methods, but the best I have come up with is:

```
location /wiki/ {
    proxy_pass http://mediawiki:80/;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}

location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass http://app1:4000/;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}


if ($http_referer = "https://sub.example.com/wiki/") {
    set $proxypass http://mediawiki:80;
}
if ($http_referer = "https://sub.example.com/app1/") {
    set $proxypass http://app1:4000;
}
    
location / {
    proxy_pass $proxypass;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Since I am not able to configure a baseurl for the mediawiki (yet), I tried to proxy incoming requests at the root location depending on the `http_referer`. This works for all inital GET requests made at `https://sub.example.com/wiki/` and also for the link mentioned above.

However, after clicking `<a href="/mw-config/index.php">...`, `index.php` makes further requests - again directed to `https://sub.example.com/`. Since the URL is not rewritten and the referer says `https://sub.example.com/mw-config/index.php`, these requests return 500.

My question is: How can I fix this behaviour to make my apps permanently reside at their respective location? I can unfortunately not change the subdomain at this point.

Any help is appreciated!

##### Edit:

---

Since I want to use multiple other apps that may encounter similar problems, I would like to come up with a more general solution. In some cases I do not have control over the base URL.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few of things going on here that we need to get on the same page for this to work:

1. **NGINX** configuration: path based routing, reverse proxy

   - I've tried your config, and **I believe your config is correct**
2. **Apache2** configuration: correctly map URI to file paths and scripts

   - Use a directive `AliasMatch "^/wiki(.*)" "/var/www/html/$1"` to strip the `/wiki` and map to internal file paths correctly
3. **MediaWiki** settings: add the `/wiki` path so that `Nginx` knows where to reverse proxy the links, and then `Apache2` can strip out the `/wiki` and use the correct internal file paths.

   - Set `$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";` in the `LocalSettings.php` file created after running the MediaWiki setup, and override that file in your `docker-compose.yml`
4. **Docker Compose**: Persist those changes by mounting our modified local files into the `mediawiki` docker container

### Apache2

We're going to add `AliasMatch "^/wiki(.*)" "/var/www/html/$1"` to the configuration at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. You'll also need to override the contents of this file in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        AliasMatch "^/wiki(.*)" "/var/www/html/$1"

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

### MediaWiki settings:

This is just a snippet of the `LocalSettings.php` file that needs to be changed. It's a bit big to include the whole default here. It looks like you already have a local copy of `LocalSettings.php` that you're mounting into the docker container using docker-compose, so just modify the `$wgScriptPath` variable there and restart your container.

```
## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";
```

### Docker Compose

Now **we'll modified the volumes section** of the MediaWiki piece of the docker-compose.yml to **override the apache2 config** file for the MediaWiki site.

```
  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: mediawiki
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./images:/var/www/html/images
      - ./wiki/LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
      - ./apache2/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    networks:
      - wiki
```

Comment: s/"/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf"/"/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf"

Answer (score 0):

Setting the root URL is the only stable solution to this issue.

I searched "mediawiki root URL", and second hit pointed to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Ry90289pdqa86yrd, where the first response tells how to set the root URL in MediaWiki:

> The URL to your wiki must be set in LocalSettings.php (just like e.g. $wgLogo, which is also set in that file) and you can change it by setting $wgServer to another value. This will then make MediaWiki output URLs starting with the domain you want.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the configuration through LocalSettings.php and will certainly do so. However, I may encounter similar problems in other apps, e.g. a [Django admin page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/), and would therefore like to come up with a more generic solution.

Comment: It is always the CMS that generates the URLs. Therefore the only reliable solution is to set the root URL in the CMS.